# css gets overwritten by another css

Tags: css

I have this css below. Some how my this css's clicked link gets over written by some other css once I click the link. It turns the link color to red. I tried to keep it white in code below but thats not helping. What can I do to get it working

```
.grey {
    background-color:#545154;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #120c12;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
}.grey:hover {
    background-color:#a8a5a8;
}.grey:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

 .grey a:visited{
  color:white !important;
  }
 .grey a:link{
  color:white !important;;
  }
```

html

```
<a href="www.site.com" class="grey" style="color:white;">Site</a>
```

Comment: what @Shmiddty says makes sense ;)

Comment: To begin with, use your browser's developer tools to see what CSS rule causes the links to become red. Then post it here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector for the white color is off.  It should be `.grey:visited` or `a.grey:visited`.